# Shell Script to Increment the value of a varaible

Tags: shell-script

How do I make a shell script which whenever I run it increments the value of a variable. Suppose if a variable has a value of 5 and if I run the script again it increments a 1 into it. And if the value exceeds from 100 it subtracts 50 from the 100.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want a simple shell script which has a variable in it which is already assigned a value. When ever the script runs it increments a value in the variable.

Comment: Ok. Please provide a sample of what you have tried this far, and tell us where in the process you are stuck.

Comment: The variable, is it an environment variable? Are you requiring that the variable be changed in the script's environment only, or should it be changed in the calling environment too?

Comment: It should change it's value.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework. In any case, to help answer your question accurately, we'd need to know whether you're trying to change an environment variable, or just a variable inside the script as Kusalananda says. If you're unsure what an environment variable is, see here https://askubuntu.com/a/26326

Comment: Welcome to the site: So that we can answer your question, can you please make the question clear as asked (You can edit the question). Editing question is better than adding amendments as comments. (Humans are not good at understanding long lists of amendments.)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

A shell script is an application written in some shell language, it can only change the value of its own variables, not the variable of some other process like the caller here¹

If you want to increase the value of a shell variable in your shell and your shell is a POSIX-like shell, you could use a function instead:

```
incr() {
  var=$((var + 1))
  if [ "$var" -gt 100 ]; then
    var=50
  fi
}
```

Which with Korn-like shells (ksh, zsh, bash), you can shorten to:

```
incr() ((++var <= 100 || (var = 50)))
```

Or for the name of the variable to be passed as argument:

```
incr() ((++$1 <= 100 || ($1 = 50)))
```

POSIXly:

```
incr() {
  : "$((($1 = $1 + 1) <= 100 || ($1 = 50)))"
}
```

---

<sup>¹ An exception to that would be the `fish` shell with its *universal* variables which can be shared between `fish` instances</sup>